# Ayuda en Ficheros de C++

Tags: c++

Tengo creado un archivo txt con varios usuarios, algunos repetidos lo cual el ID se repite, a la hora de imprimirlo tengo problemas ya que si el usuario se repite 2 o n veces el sistema me los muestra esas veces, no se como hacer para que me lo muestre solo una vez.

```
cobrarArc.open("pendientes.txt", ios::app);

        cobrarArc>>filial[10];
        bool ver = false;
        cout<<"Registros de pagos Pendientes\n"<<endl;
        cout<<"Filial:"<<endl;
        cin>>BusFilial;
        while(!cobrarArc.eof()) {
            cobrarArc>>cobro>>mes>>anio;
            if(filial[10] == BusFilial) {
                ver = true;
                    cout<<"Cliente: "<<filial[10]<<endl;
                       cout<<"Pagos Pendientes: "<<endl;
                      cout<<mes<<" "<<anio<<" "<<cobro<<endl;
            }

            cobrarArc>>filial[10];

        }
        if(ver == false) {
            cout<<"Filial no existe.."<<endl;
        }

        cobrarArc.close();

    system("pause");
    system("cls");
```

Comment: Ves ingresando en una Array los ID ya imprimidos, y antes va mostrar cada uno lo vas comparando con ese arreglo a ver si ya se a mostrado en la ventana

Comment: quieres ver esto [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition (i.e. while (!stream.eof())) considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons)